# Why is this php code not fetching the first row from the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

It seems that this php code fetches all the rows in the database, but does not fetch the very first row. If you call to the procedure in the database (see the procedure below) it shows all the rows as expected. The database has four columns and in the code it's used echo to print out the data from the second row, What's happening is that the first record does not display, so it's not fetched I think. So, what could be the problem?

```
    //this is the broken part of my code
    $statement = $conn->prepare('call GetImage()');

        $statement->execute();

      while($row = $statement->fetch()){

    $dest_slash = str_replace('-', '/', $row[2]);
    $dest_slash_backslash = str_replace(';','\\', $dest_slash);
    $replace_root = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$dest_slash_backslash);
    $row[2] = $replace_root;

    $images_paths_with_num[] = array($image_count,$row[2]);
    $image_count++;
    echo $row[1];
  }
```

This is the stored procedure that I'am using:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`0901972749`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetImage`()
begin
    select imageID,imageName,imagePath,imageText
    from Images limit 500;
end
```

Comment: Do you have any order in the Database? You can ensure that records are shown as you want using "order by imageID" to ensure they are in the correct order you want them to be.

Comment: Are you able to fetch the first row through a hardcoded query?

Comment: I fargot to mention that it works to call  to GetImage() in workbench and everything is displayed as expected, so the problem probably lies with the php code.

Comment: Sorry, there was nothing wrong with my code. Ricardo Ortega Magana is with the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a stored procedure for this. That's extremely inflexible, and there's nothing in that procedure that can't be replicated by a query with the exact same content.

Comment: I think it's better to use stored procedure instead of putting a query in my code because then you get less ,,spaghetti" in the code. That's why I use it.

Comment: I think if I'am using the same query very much. The code will be cleaner and easier to read when you use stored procedures because then the query() thing is not involved, I only need to make a call for it.

Comment: If you don't want to put queries in your code. use an ORM. Putting trivial queries in SPs definitely isn't the right way.

Comment: Good idea, I should checknit out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See this procedure (The same as in the question):

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`0901972749`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetImage`()
begin
    select imageID,imageName,imagePath,imageText
    from Images limit 500;
end
```

It was needed to add an order by statement in this case "order by imageID" to it as things were not displaying in the right order.  To be sure about the data will display in the right order, we need to use an order by clause. But, stored procedures may not be the right solution for this. Sorry about that :)

Like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`0901972749`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetImage`()
begin
    select imageID,imageName,imagePath,imageText
    from Images limit 500 order by imageID;
end
```